# registering .net assembly as com

Tags: com, assemblies, regasm

I have a C# class library which calls a native code DLL. I am trying to call this code from VBA.
I configured MSVC to register the generated DL and it works fine. I can access objects in DLL and work with them without any problem. 
I want to register them in another computer and I am using the following command:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe /tlb /v MyNetAssembly.DLL

The command return successfully but when I am trying to use the dll objects in VBA, I am getting error file not found (80070002). I tried to add path to the place that dll resides, copy the dlls to windows directory, using /codebase option, without any success.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: `/codebase` should do it. Other than that you could use Process Monitor to see where the file is searched for and act according to that.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting process monitor. I will check it on Monday.